bot composer Instagram channel
I am trying to connect my azure bot to Instagram channel, bot working fine with facebook businesss account.
Added instagram app to facebook page,  but its not working ,  or not getting any responce from instagram.
Is there any new update for instagram channel adapter from microsoft on azure bot? any help on how to build a custom adapter for instagram?
Verified community adapters but of no help

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
